# Is a license key purchase mandatory for creating a native android app for a Magento web store?

Tags: android, magento, mobile, native

I'm looking into developing a native android application for an existing Magento web store, and then submitting the application to Google Play. I've read through several resources, but I could not find a clear path to get started.

The [Magento Mobile section](http://www.magentocommerce.com/products/mobile#how-it-works) of the official website suggests a mandatory purchase of a license key and submission of the app; with this, Magento will manage the code for an annual fee. Is this the only method to approach native Magento mobile development?

Is there a way to use a Magento mobile API or API's to develop the app without the need for any license key purchases or annual fees?

If yes, what would be the relevant resources to begin with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're interested in the `Mage_XmlConnect` module that ships with Magento, located here

```
app/code/core/Mage/XmlConnect
```

Your questions a little broad for specifics, but this old [Inchoo](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/develop-your-own-magento-mobile-application/) article should get you started down the right track.